# Converting data objects in R

Tags: r

I have a data object called dat that looks like this:

```
> dat


          PC1          PC2          PC3          PC4          PC5 
 6.403056e-04 5.433502e-04 7.888467e-05 6.776798e-05 2.589316e-05
```

And I want to convert dat into this:

```
> dat
 [1] 6.403056e-04 5.433502e-04 7.888467e-05 6.776798e-05
 [5] 2.589316e-05
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: It will be easier to help specifically if you add the output of calling `dput` on a sample of data—right now, if there are data type issues here, we can't see them

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484728/convert-a-row-of-a-data-frame-to-vector

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you need to give more information – from the information you present it's not clear what type your data really is. It is possible that you have a data.frame, in which case you can go with Simon's answer. However, your output could easily be a vector with named elements, too:

```
dat <- c(PC1=6.403056e-04, PC2=5.433502e-04, PC3=7.888467e-05, PC4=6.776798e-05, PC5=2.589316e-05)
> dat
         PC1          PC2          PC3          PC4          PC5 
6.403056e-04 5.433502e-04 7.888467e-05 6.776798e-05 2.589316e-05 
> class(dat)
[1] "numeric"
```

In which case you already have what you are after, except for element labels. If you really needed to get rid of those you could drop them like this:

```
> names(dat)
[1] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" "PC5"
> names(dat) <- NULL
> dat
[1] 6.403056e-04 5.433502e-04 7.888467e-05 6.776798e-05 2.589316e-05
```

However, removing them probably has no real benefit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, you have a data frame `dat` like this:

```
> dat = data.frame(PC1=6.403056e-04, PC2=5.433502e-04, PC3=7.888467e-05, PC4=6.776798e-05,PC5=2.589316e-05) 
> dat
           PC1          PC2          PC3          PC4          PC5
1 0.0006403056 0.0005433502 7.888467e-05 6.776798e-05 2.589316e-05
```

If so, you can get a vector as follows:

```
> as.numeric(dat[1,])
[1] 6.403056e-04 5.433502e-04 7.888467e-05 6.776798e-05 2.589316e-05
```

... based on the answer to [Convert a row of a data frame to vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484728/convert-a-row-of-a-data-frame-to-vector).